# creating matplotlib text at different heights

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I want to use Matplotlib (Python package) to create text that takes characters & their frequencies and plots them on a graph at the same horizontal component but a different vertical component.

For example, if I had letters (A,J, K, & L) with frequencies of 0.25 per letter,  I want Matplotlib to show a graph with a y-axis going from 0 to 1.0:

```
    A - top at 1.00;
    J - top at 0.75;
    K - top at 0.50;
    L - top at 0.25;
```

Not a super advanced Matplotlib user, so the simpler the solution the better. If this would be easier with R, please let me know.

Comment: Just to make sure - do you want to write text inside a figure, or to plot bars at different heights?

Comment: @BossaNova I want it to look like: http://blog.tinyray.com/weblogo/